# AngularJS route/ajax call/ 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, node.js

I am learning AngularJS with a simple app that has customers and their orders. I have a table that displays the customers with a link that leads to their orders. Upon clicking `View order`, that is the link to view a customers order from the main page, I get an internal server error from Chrome's console. I am not sure if it's a problem with routing, though the tutorial I am following did nothing extra from the codes below, unless I'm mistaken:

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/ordersController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/services/customersFactory.js"></script>
        <script src="app/services/values.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#/customers">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/orders">Orders</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>
        <div ng-view></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

### app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'CustomersController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/customers.html'
        })
        .when('/orders/:customerId', {
            controller: 'OrdersController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/orders.html'
        })
        /*when('/orders/', {
            controller: 'AllOrdersController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/allorders.html'
        })*/
        .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' });
  });
```

### customers.html

```
<h3> {{ appSettings.title }}</h3>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
<br/><br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in filtered = (customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse)">
        <td>{{ cust.name | uppercase }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.joined | date}}</td>
        <td><a href="#/orders/{{ cust.id }}">View Orders</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span> Total customers: {{ filtered.length }} </span>
<br/>
<footer>Version: {{ appSettings.version }}</footer>
```

### customersController.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, customerFactory, appSettings) { 
    'use strict';

    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.customers = [];
    $scope.appSettings = appSettings; 

    function init (){
        customerFactory.getCustomers()
            .success(function(customers) {
                $scope.customers = customers;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //error handler
            });
    }

    init();

    $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

### ordersController.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('OrdersController', function ($scope, $routeParams, customerFactory) { 
    'use strict';

    var customerId = $routeParams.customerId;
    $scope.customer = null;

    function init() {
        //Search customers for customerId
        customerFactory.getCustomer(customerId)
            .success(function(customer) {
                $scope.customer = customer;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //error handler
                //maybe pop up an alert, log it?
            });
    }

    init();

        /**
    $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }; **/

});
```

### orders.html

```
<h3>{{ customer.name }}'s Orders</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in customer.orders">
        <td>{{ order.product }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.total | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### customersFactory.js

```
(function() {
    var customerFactory = function($http) {

            var factory = {};

            factory.getCustomers = function() {
               return $http.get('/customers');
            };

            factory.getCustomer = function(customerId) {
                return $http.get('/customers/' + customerId);
            };

            return factory;

    };
            customerFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
            angular.module('myApp').factory('customerFactory', customerFactory);
}());
```

### server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

/* EXPRESS 3.0
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
});
*/

// EXPRESS 4.0
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
   // configure stuff here
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
}

/*EXPRESS 3.0
app.get('/customers/:id', function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
            data = customer[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data)
});
*/

//EXPRESS 4.0
app.route('/customers/:id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
            data = customer[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data)
    })

app.route('/orders/:id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = cutomers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
            data = customers[i][orders];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data)
    })

/* EXPRESS 3.0
app.get('/customers', function(req, res) {
    res.json(customers);
});
*/

//EXPRESS 4.0
app.route('/customers')
    .get (function(req, res) {
    res.json(customers);
})


app.listen(3000);

console.log('Express listening on port 3000');


var customers = [
    { 
            id: 1,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Mayweather', 
            city: 'Brooklyn', 
            orderTotal: '43.1299',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pencils',
                total: 9.9956
              }
            ]

          }, 
          {
            id: 2,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Jason', 
            city: 'Cleveland', 
            orderTotal: '89.8933',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'iPad',
                total: 20.9956
              }
            ]  
          }, 
          {
            id: 3,
            joined: '1999-08-27', 
            name: 'Jade', 
            city: 'Wroclaw', 
            orderTotal: '77.0092',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pillows',
                total: 12.2311
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 4,
            joined: '2015-09-01', 
            name: 'David', 
            city: 'Accra', 
            orderTotal: '13.8465',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 5,
            joined: '2001-01-18', 
            name: 'Doyet',
            city: 'Paris',
            orderTotal: '23.9930',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }];
```

As you can see, the data is provided by json to the application of customers and their orders stored in an array.

From this images, in the browser, I expect to grab the users name from the `customers` array in the `server.js` so that it reads something like "Dave's Orders" and then actually displays the orders but this is not happening.

[image]

Thanks if anyone can help :D...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have misspelled 'customers' (s letter is missing) on your server side:

```
for (var i = 0, len = cutomers.length; i < len; i++) {
```

Also here you get data from undefined variable:

```
data = customer[i];
```

Comment: `data = customers[i];' doesn't fix it. I tried `data = customers[i].orders;` in an attempt to get the orders from the `orders` array. not working.

Comment: If you get 500 then something is definitely wrong on the server side – can you show the stacktrace after customers get call?

Comment: it was the typo i made. but after fixing the typo. i had to restart node for it to work. all's good like expected now. thanks for the good eye :)

Answer (score 0):

On server.js, change:

```
res.json(data);
```

To:

```
return res.json(data);
```

Comment: that doesn't make any change :)

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely server side error....or there could be issue while putting exact url in http.get
Cross check in your java file/sever side source code ..what is exact url and path params.